# As java doesn't have referencing, how does one pass information between two separate classes?

Tags: java

Sorry for the extremely vague/confusing, I really didn't know how to name this issue. If someone has a better one please feel free too edit it. Onto my issue,

```
public class Foo()
{
    String name;
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar temp = new Bar();
    }
}    

public class Bar()
{
    public Bar()
    {
        setFooName("newName");
    }

    public void setFooName(String name)
    {   
        // Is it possible call a method in Foo?
    }
}    


public class test {
    static public void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Foo foobar = new Foo();
    }
}
```

I'm still new to java so I'm  not sure if this is even possible, but using C++ I'd normally have a local variable of the 'Foo' inside the 'Boo' class and then pass a reference to the object into the constructor of Bar and then assign it to the local variable in Bar.

As java doesn't have referencing I'm stuck on the matter. The reason I want to do this is the example I have is I need to create a GUI object inside of a class and then have information from the GUI object sent back to the class it was created in.

I do hope this all makes sense, if it doesn't, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean Java doesn't have referencing?  Just pass a Foo object to your Bar class (probably in the constructor) if you need your Bar to operate on that Foo.

Comment: From what I read, doesn't this just create a copy of Foo, and not a pointer to the object itself?

Comment: @user1725794 No. Only primitives are pass by value in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass by value vs Pass by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512636/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference)

Comment: @Patashu, primitives and Objects are "pass by value". See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: Yes, objects are passed by _reference_ value (a copy of the reference is passed).

Comment: @Patashu Objects are also passed by value in the sense that the Value of the reference is passed.

Comment: @jahroy, read the link. The tutorial refers this as "pass by value". A copy of the reference is passed, not the reference itself.

Comment: ... Which results in similar behavior to "_pass by reference_" in that the properties of the Object can be mutated.

Comment: @camickr - Yes, I've read it and I understand it.  We're just using different terminology.  The point is that the OP can operate on the _reference value_ that is passed to his method to get the desired effect.

Comment: @camickr The way I understand it in my head, primitives are pass by value, objects are pass by reference and the reference to the object is itself 'pass by value'.

Comment: Yes, it is similar behaviour but that is not the terminology used by Java which causes confusion. So stick with the Java terminology to reduce confusion and questions like this won't need to be asked/clarified.

Comment: Although this _can_ be done, it shouldn't. It causes tight coupling between the classes, which is considered bad design.

Comment: @camickr - In my opinion, Java's choice of terminology is the source of all confusion.  People hear "_pass by value_" and assume that objects are copied before being passed.  This question is a perfect example.  As the comments under MadProgrammer's answer indicate, the only reason the OP asked this question is because he was thrown off by Java's choice of terminology.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're getting caught up on symantics.

The following example passes a copy of the reference of `Foo` to `Bar` via `Bar`'s constructor.  This now allows `Bar` to access properties of the instance of `Foo`.  What it doesn't allow you to do is change the reference between the two (ie assigning a new reference of `Foo` within bar will not change the previous reference)

```
public class Foo()
{
    String name;
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar temp = new Bar(this);
    }
}    

public class Bar()
{
    private Foo foo;
    public Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        setFooName("newName");
    }

    public void setFooName(String name)
    {   
        // Is it possible call a method in Foo?
    }
}    


public class test {
    static public void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Foo foobar = new Foo();
    }
}
```

`Bar` could then call any modifiers that `Foo` provides and it would change those individual properties of `Foo` for everybody who had a reference to that instance...

I hope that's close to what you're asking :P

Comment: `The following example passes a reference` - it passes a copy of the reference.

Comment: Tested the above code like suggested and it worked perfectly. I saw the "pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference" question but became extremely confused about it and wasn't sure at all. Sorry If my question was a time waste.

Comment: The confusion comes from the terms people try to use.  The important thing is to understand how it works.  When you pass an object to a method, you can call the object's methods and mutate its internal state.  The original object (that was passed to the method) will be updated.  As camickr has pointed out, a copy of the reference is what is actually passed.  This is why people _say_ that Java is always pass by value.  It just leads to confusion in my opinion, but there is an actual distinction.  In C++ you could assign a new object to the reference.  In Java you cannot.

Comment: @jahroy The last two sentences should have been an answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this in Java.  Java has references, but not pointers.  Confusingly, for C++ aficionados, these references can be null.

This means you can certainly do the following:

```
public class Bar {
    private Foo foo;
    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public setFooName(String name) {
        foo.setName(name);
    }
}
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    public Foo() {
        Bar temp = new Bar(this);
        temp.setFooName("fooname");
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure, in this instance, why you wouldn't just write:

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    public Foo() {
        this.name = "fooname";
    }
}
```

Comment: The example was a much simplified version of the code I'm currently working with. I thought it'd be easier to show the issue with some simple code than have you fight with my many lines of code.